# Заход на сайт с сохраненным аккаунтом

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, авторизация, регистрация

Прочитал https://htmlweb.ru/php/example/avtorizacija2.php, но не понял как сделать так чтобы при входе на сайт автоматически отображался аккаунт пользователя, если пользователь не вышел из него в прошлый раз посещения сайта (ну к примеру как тут на stackoverflow

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Чтобы при каждом посещении сайта пользователь был авторизован, если он до этого не выходил с аккаунта.

Comment: Вы имеете ввиду чтобы при каждом посещении сайта пользователь был авторизирован, если он до этого не выходил с аккаунта? Т.е чтобы ему не приходилось вводить каждый раз логин и пароль для входа?

Comment: ну так в Cookies, например, сохранить id сессии. При любом посещении сайта будут доступны его куки, сохраненные в этом браузере. Соответственно читаете в вашем коде куки, отправляете на сервер, на сервере проверяется наличие этой сессии в БД и выдается информация, авторизован или не авторизован пользователь. если авторизован, то отдаете нужные данные, а на странице отображаете нужный блок

Answer (score 0):

```
 $token = bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(10));
```

полученный таким образом токен сохраняем в куку и в БД.

при заходе на сайт, если нет авторизации, но есть кука с таким значением, то найти ее в бд, и авторизовать пользователя.
если  куки нет или значение не найдено, то показать форму авторизации

после использования токена поменять на новый

Comment: А что если просто [продлить жизнь стандартной php-сессии](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4574334)? Помимо захламления сервера файлами сессий, есть ещё какие-то проблемы, которые я упускаю?

Comment: ну или так, но тогда хранить их в БД, и не забывать регенерировать

Comment: @Ипатьев Зачем менять токен и как это сделать?

Answer (score 0):

Механизм со стороны фронтенда очень прост. После регистрации или входа в бэка приходит token. Его мы кидаем в `localStorage`(`localStorage.setItem('token', token)`). При выходе пользователя мы удаляем(`localStorage.removeItem('token')`). При входе мы смотрим есть этот токен(`localStorage.getItem('token')`). Если он есть, то авторизируем пользователя, если нет, то кидаем на страницу авторизации.

Answer (score 0):

Вообще-то практика `вечного авто-логина` не очень хорошая идея. Достаточно представить, что пользователь Вашего сайта будет заходить из какого-нибудь Интернет-кафе или с чужого компьютера и забудет сделать `logout`... Но, условия задачи ставите Вы - Вам и все риски в руки :)

Итак, мой алгоритм:

1. Авторизуем пользователя через логин и пароль.
2. При успешной авторизации выдаем пользователю `session_id`(уникальный ID его сессии он же токен) - генерируете его по своему усмотрению каким угодно алгоритмом. Например `md5(time()+<user_id>)`. Так же генерируем пользователю уникальный `<cookie_id>`
3. Сохраняем `<session_id>` и `<cookie_id>` в БД. Также `<session_id>` сохраняем в `$_SESSION`, а `<cookie_id>` в браузер. Для выполнения условий задачи выставляем для `<cookie_id>` неограниченное время жизни.
4. При любом обращении к сайту проверяем есть ли значение переменной `<session_id>` в `$_SESSION`, если есть проверяем что пользователь с таким `<session_id>` в БД существует.
5. Если `<session_id>` в `$_SESSION` нет - значит истекло ее время жизни установленное в `php.ini`
6. Если время истекло обращаемся к `$_COOKIE` и смотрим есть ли там `<cookie_id>`, проверяем, что есть пользователь в БД с таким `<cookie_id>`.
7. Если в п.6 все успешно - заново выполняем п.2 и п.3 и далее по алгоритму.

У меня так сделано на большом кол-ве `живых` проектов. Только у меня еще ограничено время жизни `cookie_id`, чтобы избежать `вечного авто-логина`.