# Id сессии и cookie

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, cookie, сессия

Как сохранить id cессии в cookie и отправить id на сервер (см. [Фиксация авторизованности](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1195642/%D0%97%D0%B0%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82-%D1%81-%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%85%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC-%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%83%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC) и [Список действий](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1195784/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0-%D1%81-cookies) - пункты 1 и 4)?

P.S. Я полагаю `$_Session['id'] = someValue`, а затем `setCookie(id, $_Session['id'], ...` - это сохранение `id` сессии в куке. Внесите ясность как точно.

Comment: Сессией управляет сервер, он ставит куки и он же получает их при каждом запросе. JavaScript тут не при чём, если попытаетесь делать это на нём, то сразу будет дыра в безопасности.

Comment: @Softovick а вы как считаете?

Comment: @PavelGrishaev а как же setCookie (вы написали 
Сессией управляет сервер, он ставит куки и он же получает их при каждом запросе.)

Comment: Поставить куки можно и на JS. Но это просто незащищённые куки, они не предназначены для сессии, и потом получите взлом, например через XSS-атаку.

Comment: @PavelGrishaev я думаю, что `$_Session['id'] = someValue`, а затем `setCookie($_Session['id'], ...` - это сохранение `id` сессии в куке.

Comment: @PavelGrishaev вернее `setCookie(id, $_Session['id'], ...`